# Android creates incorrect array list with method Arrays.asList

Tags: java, android, arrays

i have array

```
                    int[] pressed= new int[]{1,2,3};

                    List pS = Arrays.asList(pressed);
```

i expect what pS will contains array of integers with 1,2,3 values, but it contains array with one element which is a array of {1,2,3}

[image]

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you? If so, please consider upvoting and/or accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use a primitive type as a generic in Java. If you can't change the **int[]** into an **Integer[]**, you will have to convert it by adding all the items yourself, like this:

```
public class ArrayUtil {

    public static ArrayList<Integer> asList(int[] array) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        if(array != null){
            for(int i=0; i<array.length; ++i){
                list.add(array[i]);
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

}
```

And to call it:

```
List pS = ArrayUtil.asList(pressed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Arrays.asList(1,2,3);`. The var-arg method `asList()` is treating your primitive array as one object and creates a list consisting of it. This shouldn't happen with reference types.

Alternatively declare pressed as `Integer[]`.

Comment: i cant create lsit with variable params, because array i got from system function call, and it's return only int[] array.

Comment: @DmitryNelepov Then don't use `Arrays#asList()`.